# Cannot connect to API: Should I use websocket or something else?

Tags: javascript, api, websocket

I have this API: http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/2.2 which says:

### Communication with the xStation API

There are two IPs, that can be used interchangeably:

- xapia.x-station.eu
- xapib.x-station.eu

Here are the addresses of DEMO and REAL servers:

- DEMO: main port: 5124, streaming port: 5125
- REAL: main port: 5112, streaming port: 5113.

Both servers use SSL connection.

I'd like to login to my account but I just don't know how to connect to this API. I figured, the right way might be to use websocket which I've never used before...

```
websocket = new WebSocket("ws://xapia.x-station.eu:5124");
```

...but didn't even connect to server.

Could anyone provide me with some simple example or at least point me to right direction? This is completely new to me and don't know where to start.

Comment: The API you refer to looks like it uses a plain SSL TCP connection (not a webSocket) and you must send requests as properly formatted JSON.  If you were connecting to this API, you would use a plain socket as described in the [nodejs Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options).

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to get myself more familiar with node.js then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make this into an answer since it looks like it answers your question.

The API you refer to looks like it uses a plain SSL TCP connection (not a webSocket) and you must send requests as properly formatted JSON. If you were connecting to this API, you would use a plain socket as described in the [nodejs Net module](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html).

> Cannot connect to API: Should I use websocket or something else?

You should be using a plain TCP socket, not a webSocket.  A webSocket is a higher level protocol that runs on top of a TCP socket.  It can only connect to a webSocket server.

Comment: Sure, it really helped! I was able to fiddle around with it, establish connection and sent some data. But I somehow cannot get any data back. I am wondering if it might be due to SSL requirement. I've never used SSL before. Do you think this might be the reason and if so, could you give me another hint how to solve it? :)

Comment: Hmm, so I was able to get response and login to my account using https://packetsender.com/ I had to use SSL and persistent TCP which I don't know how to use with node.js.  Would you have any idea? I am almost there! :))

Comment: @jbrychra - you can do plain tcp with the Net module.